# ¿Que significa esta expresión?

Tags: java

Estaba trabajando con hilos y encontre este códido:

http://www.webtutoriales.com/articulos/comunicacion-entre-un-servidor-y-multiples-clientes.

Pero me llamo la atención esta linea:

```
((ServidorHilo) new ServidorHilo(socket, idSecion)).start();
```

¿Que es lo que significa? Al verla pareciera que esta haciendo un casting pero ¿Que significa en realidad?. No comprendo muy bien el concepto. Gracias!

Comment: Solo es la creación de una nueva instancia, seguida de la llamada a su metodo `start()`, cabe decir que una vez hecho, no se puede acceder a la instancia de `ServidorHilo` cuando se crea de esta forma _(O eso creo)_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Teniendo en cuenta que en el ejemplo ServidorHilo hereda de Thread, el metodo start() inicia el hilo.
Por otra parte el casteo que realiza no tiene sentido práctico, simplemente es una redundancia innecesaria.
Seria exactamente lo mismo escribir

new ServidorHilo(socket, idSecion)).start();

Comment: Es correcto el casteo es innecesario, redundante.

Comment: Muchas gracias!. Me imaginaba algo así pero no se mucho y dude.